# Importing file from email

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.1

I just found a very useful link, I just want to know that can I use this in **Xcode 3.1.4** with **iPhone SDK 3.1** (Mac OS X 10.5. Leopard )

I am trying to do that, but can't find the following attributes in the **info.plist**.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app

Comment: It's not available for iOS 3.1

Comment: is there any other way of importing a csv file from email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIFileSharingEnabled` and `CFBundleDocumentTypes` did not become available until iOS SDK 3.2.  For additional information, take a look at section title **File and Document Support** on [What's New in iOS 3.2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS3_2.html).

Answer (score 0):

it is so late, but i still answer.
In  IOS sdk 3.2, You can add this attribute by
 + from dropdown list, it is Application Support iTunes file Share
 + open file info.plist as source code, and add this 
        UIFileSharingEnabled
    
Hope this help someone!